# Create front end member login

Tags: login, front-end

I am very new at all this and not a programmer. I want to know how to create member login section on the site allowing users to see data that is not visible to the public. I am not sure how to go about doing this, is there a widget that one may suggest that does not take a brain surgeon to make it work. I am using the Unite theme and the site I am trying to put together is at tmpfire.com. I would appreciate all the help I can get. 
Thank you

Comment: What kind of section/page are you talking about though, a page accessible in the administration area or a page created in WordPress(eg. About page). For pages(posts, etc), the solution would be to mark a given page(or posts, whatever) as `private` when publishing.

Comment: I am looking to have web pages restricted to the public and viewable depending on how you are when you login

Comment: That's what the private setting is for... viewable to logged in users, but not to visitors(non-registered users).

Comment: This is a good plug-in to restrict users when logging into the wordpress. It is not what I am trying to achieve, so if I have not managed to be clear on what I am looking for.
I wish to have pages that I have already created restricted to the viewing public (that is on the front end) and only visible to a user that has to login to view these restricted pages through the front end of the web site. I hope I have not confused you.

Comment: have you tried what Lynne suggested?

Answer (score 1):

[User Roll Editor (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) lets you assign permissions to users via an easy toggle box interface. "Read Posts" is an option there, so you should be able to assign that permission to only people logged in under a certain roll. You can set the default log in roll to contributor, for instance, and manage that rolls permissions so they can't post but can read content.

As for front page login forms, in my opinion the best one out there is [Simple Modal Login (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplemodal-login/), it's very attractive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like this - [Role Scoper (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)

Never used it myself so can't rate it but it looks like it'll be able to do what you require.

Comment: Thank you I will try it out and see if I can get it to do what I am hoping to achieve

Comment: This is a good plug-in to restrict users when logging into the wordpress. It is not what I am trying to achieve, so if I have not managed to be clear on what I am looking for.
I wish to have pages that I have already created restricted to the viewing public (that is on the front end) and only visible to a user that has to login to view these restricted pages through the front end of the web site. I hope I have not confused you.

Comment: Role Scoper should do what you're looking for. You can set restrictions on a per-page, per-post, or per-category basis. It sounds like the missing piece you're looking for is a front-end login form. Try Login with Ajax http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-with-ajax/ or a similar plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting ready to do create a member login system myself.

One way I've seen it done is to have a search box where the user input their email address.  The resulting page is a login page which is dedicated to that user.  They would login using their username and password for the content you control from that login page.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: LEt me know how you did it once you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want your site for logged-in users only you can use [Private WordPress (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-wordpress/).

Comment: I can update this answer and help with the front-end login too but I'm not sure if you will need it after using the above plugin. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress ‘theme my login’ plugin themes the WordPress login, registration and forgot password pages according to your current theme. It creates a page to use in place of `wp-login.php`, using a page template from your theme. It also includes a widget for sidebar login.For more detail please see [my article](http://www.sthaanil.com.np/wordpress-front-end-login-registration-using-the-plugin-theme-my-login/).

Comment: You should mention, that the user has to create those templates.